# How to get a match on lookup list using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to find a  way of achieving the following using Linq.

I have a lookup list that contains a class with 3 pieces of information:

```
int Period
int MinValue
int MaxValue
```

I also have a database that contains products - each product contains the same 3 variables as in the lookup list.

I want to return products where the Period matches an entry in the lookup list and MinValue >= and MaxValue <= those in the lookup list.

```
var q = products.Where(x => ...
```

Anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
var q = products.Where(x => LookupList.Any(
                                          s => s.Period == x.Period && 
                                          x.MinValue >= s.MinValue && 
                                          x.MaxValue <= s.MaxValue));
```

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding the sequence can be filtered with the following statement.

```
var q = products.Where(
  x => Lookp.Any( y => x.Period == y.Period
                       && x.MinValue >= y.MinValue
                       && x.MaxValue <= y.MaxValue) );
```

Here, `x` is a variable for the members of `products` and `y` is a variable for the members of `Lookup`.